# Type() cannot conform to 'View' in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was wondering if anyone could help explain why I might be getting the error:

> Type'()' cannot conform to 'View'

I've been looking at a few other posts that have had similar troubles with the error but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my code for reference:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack {
            HeaderComponent()
            Spacer(minLength: 10)
            
                if (!matchSet.mSet.isEmpty) {
                    VStack { //**this is where the error is occurs**
                        matchSet.mSet.forEach { college in
                            CollegeButton(name: college.dest.name)
                        }
```

Here is the CollegeButton struct as well

```
struct CollegeButton: View {
var name: String

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print("You clicked " + name)
    }) {
        Text(name.uppercased())
            .modifier(ButtonModifier())
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) You seems to be missing some basic concepts

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `.forEach` in `SwiftUI`, instead try this:

```
ForEach(matchSet.mSet) { college in
    CollegeButton(name: college.dest.name)
}
```

The Key difference is that `ForEach` is a `View`, and `.forEach` is of type `Void`. Just make sure mSet conforms to `Identifiable`.